# Postgres data changed when copying

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have an sql file that (along with many other things) copies data from a csv file to a postgres database table. The sql file contains this command:

```
\COPY stg_gebruikers(gbr_id,klt_id,rol_id,email,ind_actief,ind_bevestigd,wachtwoord,datum_aanmaak) FROM 'stg_gebruikers.csv' WITH DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;
```

The file stg_gebruikers.csv contains the following:

```
gbr_id;klt_id;rol_id;email;ind_actief;ind_bevestigd; wachtwoord;datum_aanmaak
1;1;2;Admin;1;1; sha1:64000:18:cz6hWKx5YG/7LzIYtM+UVu7mYLHTDSRc:VJJ179dwAOnyjJbv1tsZNeMy; 11-4-2018 00:00
2;12;1;demo;1;1; sha1:64000:18:rtTvjCN/p6ak6cB5n00JslVin7i7jjrY:Kqqn6HKHX8It4ZZCfAywRRpl; 11-4-2018 00:00
```

The field 'wachtwoord' (means password in Dutch) is filled with an already encrypted password. When I run the complete script, the value that ends up in field 'wachtwoord' is different from what is in the csv file. Even stranger, on subsequent runs, the password is filled with different values

Logging output first run:

```
11:09:48.549 ... DEBUG ... - doin: INSERT INTO stg_gebruikers (gbr_id,klt_id,rol_id,email,ind_actief,ind_bevestigd,wachtwoord,datum_aanmaak) VALUES (1,1,2,'Admin',true,true, 'sha1:64000:18:+eyO/5Yd6FunshgDYY/o5hxncey6+oz9:pZ4eNhI/gMO7ujanLCFBxukD',current_timestamp)
11:09:48.769 ... DEBUG ... - doin: INSERT INTO stg_gebruikers (gbr_id,klt_id,rol_id,email,ind_actief,ind_bevestigd,wachtwoord,datum_aanmaak) VALUES (2,12,1,'demo',true,true, 'sha1:64000:18:decGMCFVX2XeN7qHSeCvpGHgFmoe3qVZ:/xU7PsttviAVeg9O1Ii8fluP',current_timestamp)
```

Logging output second run:

```
11:30:45.341 ... DEBUG ... - doin: INSERT INTO stg_gebruikers (gbr_id,klt_id,rol_id,email,ind_actief,ind_bevestigd,wachtwoord,datum_aanmaak) VALUES (1,1,2,'Admin',true,true, 'sha1:64000:18:Bqh7+emzuzJsixtwKbQ11aSc32LOZ4l+:8YR85LoNjNIef17f+Girmuk6',current_timestamp)
11:30:45.452 ... DEBUG ... - doin: INSERT INTO stg_gebruikers (gbr_id,klt_id,rol_id,email,ind_actief,ind_bevestigd,wachtwoord,datum_aanmaak) VALUES (2,12,1,'demo',true,true, 'sha1:64000:18:W2k95Oc6uY0MSYAViWnTe3eKbTqTqeA3:vkBrOCp3RO5UlzwvXHHizafS',current_timestamp)
```

The value after sha1:64000:18 is different, even though the source files did not change.

I thought that perhaps the password value itself was being encrypted so I tried changing 'sha1:64000:18:decGMCFVX2XeN7qHSeCvpGHgFmoe3qVZ:/xU7PsttviAVeg9O1Ii8fluP' to 'sha1:64000:18:abc' hoping the password would be 'abc' but it wasn't.

If i manually do an update of the value as defined in the csv for user Admin (thus: 'sha1:64000:18:cz6hWKx5YG/7LzIYtM+UVu7mYLHTDSRc:VJJ179dwAOnyjJbv1tsZNeMy') in the field wachtwoord, then it sets the correct password.

This is the create table statement for stg_gebruikers:

```
CREATE TABLE STG.STG_GEBRUIKERS(
 GBR_ID BigSerial NOT NULL,
 KLT_ID Bigint NOT NULL,
 ROL_ID Bigint NOT NULL,
 EMAIL Character varying(200) NOT NULL,
 IND_ACTIEF Boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
 IND_BEVESTIGD Boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
 IND_GEEN_VOORKEUREN Boolean,
 WACHTWOORD Character varying(100) NOT NULL,
 DATUM_AANMAAK Timestamp NOT NULL
)
```

I have looked through documentation but I could not find anything on this.

Comment: Could you also add a create table statement for `stg_gebruikers`?

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: That's really weird, I tried here using copy and it seems to work fine. Can you try this in your console? `psql testdb -c "COPY stg_gebruikers(gbr_id,klt_id,rol_id,email,ind_actief,ind_bevestigd,wachtwoord,datum_aanmaak) FROM '/home/jones//nl.csv' WITH DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;"`

Comment: Or this here, in case client and db are not in the same machine: `cat /home/jones/nl.csv | psql testdb -c "COPY stg_gebruikers(gbr_id,klt_id,rol_id,email,ind_actief,ind_bevestigd,wachtwoord,datum_aanmaak) FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;"`

Comment: I tried it, and it copies the data exactly as it should be so the passwords are correct. I am surprised by this.

Comment: One last try to understand it: which collation are you using for your database? Would you mind if I answer the question with this psql command? The only difference I see is that you used `\COPY` and  I used `COPY`